# Fetch elements with DOMXPath

Tags: php, html, dom, domxpath

I want to scrape Google search results..

How to fetch all `<div class="g">` elements without defining the absolute path?

This pattern `//h3[@class="r"]` will fetch all `h3` elements

This pattern `//div[@class="g"]` returns nothing

## html

```
...
    <div id="ires">
        <ol>
            <div class="srg">
                <div class="g">
                    ...
                        <h3 class="r"></h3>
                    ...
                </div>
                <div class="g">
                    ...
                        <h3 class="r"></h3>
                    ...
                </div>
            </div>
        </ol>
    </div>
...
```

## code

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.google.dk/search?q='.urlencode($query).'&start=0&num=100');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$html = curl_exec($ch);
$httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);

libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$doc->validateOnParse = false;
$doc->standalone = true;
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = true;
$doc->strictErrorChecking = false;
$doc->substituteEntities = false;
$doc->recover = true;
$doc->formatOutput = true;
$doc->loadHTML($html);
libxml_clear_errors();

$div = $doc->getElementById('ires');

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
foreach($xpath->query('//div[@class="g"]', $div) as $node){
    print_r($node);
}
```

Comment: You have included a concise example and test code, which is a good start. But you haven't actually explained what currently happens when you run this code, and what you want to happen instead. Do you get errors? Are elements displayed which you don't want? Is output missing which you expected?

Comment: there is no output.. I need the query pattern to fetch all `<div class="g">` elements as explained in the question

Comment: Then your question should explain that. Click [edit] and add as much detail as possible; we shouldn't have to guess or ask.

Comment: You could also try a bit of basic debugging (or, if you already have, show us the result): What happens if you dump `$div`? What if you dump the result of the `$xpath->query()` call, rather than looping over it? Have you tried simpler XPath expressions?

Comment: I just tried your code in an online test service, and it seems to work fine: http://codepad.viper-7.com/lnDxE2 Have you tried it with this exact example HTML? Maybe you've over-simplified to the point the problem can no longer be reproduced?

Comment: the example is simplified.. You need to test it on a search result form google

Comment: Then the example is useless; if we can't reproduce your problem based on the information in your question, then we can't answer it. Please [read this help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Save a real search result from Google, and simplify it to the smallest version that still reproduces the problem, but no smaller. That's how debugging works.

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
try{
$ch = curl_init();
   if (FALSE === $ch)
    throw new Exception('failed to initialize');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.google.ie/search?q=whereNotnull+laravel+5&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=FuezVfedF6aC7gaYiJiYBw");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Firefox/14.0');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $content = curl_exec($ch);
  if (FALSE === $content)
    throw new Exception(curl_error($ch), curl_errno($ch));
curl_close($ch);
} catch(Exception $e) {
trigger_error(sprintf(
    'Curl failed with error #%d: %s',
    $e->getCode(), $e->getMessage()),
    E_USER_ERROR);
}

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($content);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
```

select all divs with class "g"

```
   $xpath_resultset =  $xpath->query('//div[@class="g"]');
```

loop through $hpath_result nodes

```
  foreach($xpath_resultset as $result){
```

echo node as a text

```
   echo $dom->saveHTML($result);
```

echo node as html code

```
   echo htmlspecialchars($dom->saveHTML($result)); // echo as html code
}
```

Comment: the result is still empty

Comment: While there may be some useful code here, there is no explanation of what you have changed, or how this relates the example in the question.

Comment: And incidentally, curl never throws exceptions, so your catch block is entirely pointless.

Comment: @IMSoP is this better

Comment: Yes, that's a little better; I don't think it answers the question, but I think that's the OP's fault - the original code works for me already. The whole curl section could just be dropped, though, because the question includes the HTML hard-coded.